# Are tables still considered good practice for a layout arrangement like this [IMG inside]?

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]

What is a good way to arrange images in the footer as shown in this mockup with HTML/CSS? Are tables still considered good practice ?

Comment: Do the images on each row relate to one another somehow to form a complete "record" of data?  Think about how you use grids and tables in real life or how you view them in print.  If you can't solidly say, "Yes" to that question, then the answer is no

Comment: Tables have NEVER been considered good practice for anything other than presenting tabular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are good as well and the fact that you use tables doesnt mean you alcheic, its your choice, but i think u can as well use lists and style it in the css...

something like these

```
<ul class='abc'>
<li><img src='a.jpb' /></li>
......
</ul>
```

in your css

```
.abc li img{ margin: 10px;}
```

and you are done and style as much you like

Answer (score 4):

Stay away from using tables unless your data is tabular.

For the example image you have provided, it can be as simple as styling up the `<img />` tag its self.

Stick the images inside a `<div>` element, float them all, display inline and then add padding/margins.

A very very basic demo can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/pQDP3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table for that and if it's going to be a static set of images over time, then that would be acceptable. If the amount of images may vary over time, you could make a UL and each LI would be another image. From there, set your css rules something like:

```
#footer ul {
list-style: none;
} 

#footer ul li {
display: inline;
float: left;
width: ###px;
height ###px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tables are only meant for displaying data. For a footer you can easily use `divs` and just `float` them all. Or you could use a list and style it accordingly, but its really your choice.
 A table can do the job, but don't get caught using tables for things that tables are not meant for.